# python return function(sql statement error)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I can return commands in my return function but something need to improve:
1. I am trying to get "enable" and "conf t"command in "function" field everytime.

B4(select function and type)(I can return my commands):

```
def readrouter(x, y):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x, y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

a = raw_input("x:")
b = raw_input("y:")
for result in readrouter(a,b):
    print (result[0])
```

After:(select enable, conf t, and "commands")

```
def readrouter(x):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",(x))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

a = raw_input("x:")
for result in readrouter(a):
    print (result[0])
```

Hope you know what I mean but now I cant do what I want.
It presents:

```
x:create vlan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/f0449492/Desktop/2015225/database.py", line 323, in <module>
    for result in readrouter(a):
  File "C:/Users/f0449492/Desktop/2015225/database.py", line 318, in readrouter
    cur.execute("SELECT  command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",(x))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use `(x,)` instead of `(x)`.  The former is a 1-length tuple, the latter is just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `.execute` function expects the args passed in to be an iterable, even if there's only one item.  When you have

```
cur.execute('QUERY', (x))
```

This is equivalent to

```
cur.execute('QUERY', x)
```

So the `execute` method tries to iterate over `x` to get its arguments.  Instead, pass in `x` inside a collection:

```
cur.execute('QUERY', (x,))
# OR
cur.execute('QUERY', [x])
```